# Il s'est coupé au/le menton

Tags: prépositions

This could have been asked here but I haven't found an answer. Duolingo has shown me both versions.

> Lundi matin, il s'est coupé le menton en se rasant.
> Il s'est coupé au menton.

I seem to have seen much more sentences with "le/la" with similar verbs/constructions. "Il s'est brûlé la main" "Il s'est cassé le bras"

But it seems to be "Il s'est blessé au pied"? Why does it need à here? So sentences like "Il s'est blessé la main" " Il s'est blessé le bras" are wrong? Why? [This answer](https://hinative.com/questions/17530899) seems to suggest au and le both work?

I'm familiar with phrases like "avoir mal au pied" and " se faire mal au bras" and these seem to always include the preposition à?

Comment: *He cut off his foot!* ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference, but not all speakers apply it.

> Alice s'est blessé l'épaule.

Literally : "Alice hurt her shoulder"

Here the central point of examination is Alice's shoulder. What is its state? It is hurt.

> Alice s'est blessée à l'épaule

Literally : "Alice hurt herself at the shoulder"

Here the central point is Alice. What is her state? Hurt. More precisely, hurt at the level of her shoulder.

In some cases it matters a lot :

> Il s'est coupé au doigt.

He got a cut and it happened to concern his finger. Perhaps a small accident while peeling potatoes.

> Il s'est coupé le doigt.

He cut off his finger.

Now for your first sentence

> Lundi matin, il s'est coupé le menton en se rasant.

Literally I would understand it as this person cutting off his chin, but with the context one could guess it probably isn't that bad.

"Se faire mal" and "Avoir mal" are different and don't work the same. Here "mal" is already the COD of "avoir" and you can't add a second one.

Comment: Context matters. I say *je me suis coupé le doigt* even when it's a small cut. If I really cut off my finger, my tone will reveal it. *Je me suis coupé au doigt* sounds a little clumsy to me.

Answer (score 1):

It could equally well be "il s'est blessé le pied". Both work in all cases, it seems. "avoir mal au" is a different story, "le" is not possible there.